# Finding remoteness of point using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-analysis

I'm sure this shouldn't be as tricky as I'm finding it but does anyone know how you can find the 'remoteness' of a point compared to multiple other points in QGIS?

I have a shapefile containing 1000's of points, and I want to find out which one of them is the most remote. What I mean by remote is:

*"the state of being distant from something else"*

Comment: Find distance of nearest neighbor to each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `vector - analysis tool - distance matrix`, set your point-layer as both start and target, provide an id-column in the attribute table and there you are. Logically you could set `k` to 1, so you only get the closest point to each point - but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Worked a treat!